# built-in predicate statistics in a Bratko example doesn't behave as expected

Tags: prolog, amzi-prolog

I'm trying out exercise 4.3 of Bratko with the addition of statistics. It seems that the moment I add statistics, I'm getting a 'no' answer from Prolog or in some cases it ends up in an endless loop...

For instance, this questions gives me a clear answer of the Schedule:

```
?- schedule(riva at Start, riva at End, Schedule), 
    member(arrive(malcesine at _), Schedule), 
    before(17:00, Start).
```

But if I add statistics like this:

```
?- statistics(runtime, T1), 
    schedule(riva at Start, riva at End, Schedule), 
    member(arrive(malcesine at _), Schedule), 
    before(17:00, Start), 
    statistics(runtime, T2).
```

Prolog answers 'no'.

Could the reason be that I'm using Amzi Prolog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predicate `statistics/2` is not a standard predicate (although found in some Prolog implementations). What do you get if you try the goal:

```
?- predicate_property(statistics(_, _), built_in).
```

Or:

```
?- predicate_property(statistics(_, _), imported_from(amzi_system))
```

If both goals fail, you may want to look at any libraries provided by your Prolog system to check if similar functionality is available.